# Google maps V3 drag map with right mouse button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In a normal map, if you left-click mostly anywhere and drag, the map pans.

My question is: can you swap left and right buttons to pan the map? That is, left-clicking and dragging does nothing, while panning happens with right-clicking and dragging?

Perhaps there's a JavaScript hack unrelated to Google Maps to accomplish this?

Comment: With Greasemonkey it should be possible but I do not believe that you can change Google javascripts in any other way ;-)

Comment: It my be possible by trapping the DOM mousedown event and triggering the corresponding map event, but... Why do you want to swap buttons over?

Comment: I want to be able to click and drag to draw a line, like in MS Paint. With default behavior, you would be dragging instead. I could have the right button control line drawing but it feels unnatural. I'll think of a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most other sites solve this by using different modes of using the map. For example when you click a "draw" button you enter "drawing mode" which just disables some Google Maps features like dragging and enables the drawing functionality.

That's the only way I can think of this'll work. Using the right mouse button to draw feels wrong and most users will probably agree i'm afraid.